# c++ variable declaration syntax

Tags: c++

When I take something as simple as this:

```
char text1[] = "hello world";
MessageBox(NULL, text1, NULL, NULL);
```

I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [12]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Comment: `char text1[] = ...` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, `wchar_t text1[]` (or `std::wstring`).

Comment: In C++ you would use `std::string`.

Comment: What almost no one here is mentioning is that the wide versions should be used when dealing with the winapi.

Comment: error C2039: 'string' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @user2726531, You need to include the appropriate header (and seriously, use `std::wstring`).

Comment: Why so many votes down?

Comment: @user2726531 - 'string' is resolved by including `<string>`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two basic problems. First, a `char` can only hold one character, not a string of characters. Second, you have a "narrow" character string literal, but you're (apparently) using a Unicode build of your application, in which `MessageBox` expects to receive a wide character string. You want either:

```
wchar_t text1[] = L"hello world";
```

or:

```
wchar_t const *text1 = L"hello world";
```

or (most often):

```
std::wstring text1(L"hello world");
```

...but note that an `std::wstring` can't be passed directly to `Messagebox`. You'd need to either pass `text1.c_str()` when you call `MessageBox`, or else write a small wrapper for `MessageBox` that accepted a (reference to) a `std::wstring`, something like:

```
void message_box(std::wstring const &msg) {
     MessageBox(NULL, msg.c_str(), NULL, MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: @user2726531: Sounds like you need to add `#include <string>`.

Comment: But now a new error occured: error C2601: 'MessageBoxW' : local function definitions are illegal

Comment: @user2726531: Ah, I messed up -- since `MessasgeBox` is a macro, it's replacing the name of the `MessageBox` function above with  `MessasgeBoxW`. Just rename it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a `single character`, not a String.

You need Unicode, you can use TCHAR;

```
TCHAR[] text = _T("Hello World.");
MessageBox(NULL, text, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [12]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: @user2726531 edited the answer. You just need Unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal in C/C++ is not a `char` but a collection of `char` values.  The idiomatic way of declaring this is

```
const char* text1 = "hello world";
```

Comment: error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: @user2726531 `LPCWSTR` is referring to a unicode string while `char*` or `LPCSTR` refers to an ANSI string.  If you need a unicode string use `LPCWSTR` and change the declaration to `L"hello world"`

Answer (score 0):

`char` only hold one character, not an array of characters.

So just use a pointer to constant string of Unicode characters.

`LPCWSTR text1 = L"hello world";`

Comment: first option works. Second option does not: Error error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'